# On flexbox did the wrap work on the height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to put item in column and when the window get narrow this column breaks into new column can i do this in flexbox?

Comment: You need to provide code of what you are currently tring or people will struggle to help you.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `flex-wrap` property.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: #050;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>  
</div>
```